# How to rename default-ssl.conf in Apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-ssl

I'm running Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu. I'm trying to rename`default-ssl.conf`, but I can't get it to work.

Here is what works.

If I enable the SSL module

```
a2enmod ssl
```

and the site configuration file

```
a2ensite default-ssl.conf
```

and start httpd

```
service apache2 start
```

then httpd serves on port 443 SSL-encrypted contents from `/var/www/html`, exactly as expected. So far so good.

Here is what doesn't work.

If I rename the default configuration file

```
mv /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/{default-ssl.conf,foobar}
service apache2 restart
```

then httpd sends clear text responses on port 443, and responds to "GET /"  with an index of `/var/www`.

What makes the name `default-ssl.conf` so special? How can I rename it without breaking everything?

Comment: Did you try `a2dissite default-ssl.conf`, renaming the file, `a2ensite newfilename.conf`, restarting the Apache server?

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure the new configuration name ends with `.conf`

As this is only a symlink created by the `a2ensite` command, you probably want to rename to actual configuration file:

```
a2dissite default-ssl
mv /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf \
   /etc/apache2/sites-available/foobar.conf
a2ensite foobar
service apache2 reload
```